# Flutter : disable listener pointing event on some screen

Tags: flutter

I doing a function similar like bank app, when user is idle on screen for too long, prompt a message to notice the user.

I found flutter have `Listener` widget can easily listen on any pointing event. Currently I use `Listener` wrap on app first widget (top level), so I can listen all child widget pointing event including `Dialog` `Snackbar` `Alert` `Camera` etc.

However, there are some screen I wish to by pass the `Listener`, so during those screen user wont get prompt notice when idle for too long, eg user not yet login screen like `Login` `SignUp` `Forgot Password` `OTP` etc.

```
Listener(
    onPointerDown: (e){
      print("point down");
    },
    child: mychild
),
```

UPDATE (12 March 2021) : I manage to do the idle handling function without wrap each of screen with `Listener`. And using only one `Listener` on the top level. This function support user on screen idle and app in `paused` `inactive` life cycle state. Unable to show the solution due to privacy issue. I closing this issue.

Comment: What exactly is your question here? If you don't *want* a Listener in that screen(s), don't *put* a Listener in that screen(s). It's not like it snuck in there on it's own under the cover of darkness and now you cannot get rid of it. Don't want it? Don't use it.

Comment: @nvoigt question updated, I use Listener on the top level of widget

Answer (score -1):

Then don't use the `Listener` widget on the top level, but only on the top level of the screen you *want* to use it.

Okay, to expand on that answer a bit: You are a cook with 51 dishes and because 50 of them require Ketchup, you poured Ketchup over *all* of them. And now, you are asking for help in a culinary question: how to best scrape Ketchup off from chocolate icecream.

I'm sure there is weird ways how to get Ketchup out of an icecream bowl, but the only correct answer to that question is you don't. You don't put it there in the first place.

The solution to that specific question is you don't. Now that you realize that pouring Ketchup over *all* your dishes, just because a majority needed it, was a bad idea, you are back to step one: how to handle the majority so you don't have to do them one by one? That is a valid question. And you should ask *that* question.

Just be prepared that to answer that question, people will need to know specifics about your application. Because there is a *best* answer depending on those specifics. Do you use a Bloc for navigating between logged in and not logged in states? Then that may be the place to place your Listener. But maybe you don't. Maybe you can have a common base class to all your states that already does that. Maybe that's not possible in your application. Maybe you can use a Mixin? We don't know. Maybe just a common method? If that's not possible, you are in "do it one by one" territory.

But *that* is the question to ask.

Right now, you are stuck with pouring Ketchup over your icecream and insisting that people help you with the mess, instead of finding a better solution to distribute Ketchup to the 50 dishes that need it.

Comment: if the screen want to use listener is about 95% (50 screen), and 5% is screen without listener, so do I need to do 50 screen , and 50 screen do for same function ? is this your suggestion ?

Comment: Yes, it is. If you want 50 screens with buttons and one without, you don't program all screens with buttons and try to figure out how to remove it from the one that does not have buttons. You can share code between the 50 screens, but you don't share it between 51 and then wonder how to get it *out* of one.

Comment: I am showing you a way to solve your problem. "mean" would be to "not comment, not answer" when I clearly know how to solve this. If you don't want to solve your problem this way, I cannot really help you, but that is not on me. I can only provide advice, you still have to take it to solve your problem.